# Force "possible unintended reference comparison" warning

Tags: c#

I have a type which is compared to an object of the same type (or a sub class) multiple times. For this specific type, this would be a bug. The type has a Id property which should be compared instead.

Is there some way i can mark this type so a reference check creates a build warning/error?

Sample code:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISomeData realData = new SomeData(Guid.NewGuid(), "PropValue1", "PropValue2");
        ISomeData differentViewOnTheRealData = new ChangeProperty1(realData, "OtherPropValue1");

        var refEquals = realData == differentViewOnTheRealData;       //This will return false which would be a bug
        var idEquals  = realData.BaseDataId == differentViewOnTheRealData.BaseDataId; //This will be true which is correct
    }

}

public interface ISomeData
{
    Guid BaseDataId { get; }
    string Property1 { get; }
    string Property2 { get; }
}

public class SomeData : ISomeData
{
    public SomeData(Guid id, string property1, string property2)
    {
        this.BaseDataId = id;
        Property1 = property1;
        Property2 = property2;
    }

    public Guid BaseDataId { get; }
    public string Property1 { get; }
    public string Property2 { get; }
}

//This class represents a modified view on ISomeData
public class ChangeProperty1 : ISomeData
{
    private readonly ISomeData _someData;
    private readonly string _someOtherValueForProperty1;

    public ChangeProperty1(ISomeData someData, string someOtherValueForPropertyValue)
    {
        _someData = someData;
        _someOtherValueForProperty1 = someOtherValueForPropertyValue;
    }

    public Guid BaseDataId => _someData.BaseDataId;
    public string Property1 => _someOtherValueForProperty1;
    public string Property2 => _someData.Property2;
}
```

Comment: One thing you _may_ consider is whether you should overload `operator ==` so that for two ___compile-time___ references to that type you get the desired behavior. It is not an answer to your question. It will not work if the types at compile-time is `object` or something else more general than the relevant type.

Comment: In that case, if just _one_ operand to `==` has compile-time type equal to your specific type, while the other operand has compile-time type `object`, then the compiler will issue the warning __warning CS0253: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the [left/right] hand side to type 'YourClass'__.

Comment: What you're doing here is called an "XY question". You have a problem, you have a bad idea about how to solve the problem, and now you're asking an unanswerable question about your bad non-solution.  Jeppe's comment is correct; the right way to do this is to overload `==`, `!=` and `Equals` and `GetHashcode` to correctly implement value equality, and then allow the compiler to detect unwanted reference equality. To avoid this situation, ask questions about the real problem rather than the attempt at a solution.

Comment: The idea of Jeppe's solution here is to present a "pit of success" solution to the user of your API; that is, the *natural* way and the *right* way to do a comparison should be the same. The natural way to do a comparison is `==` or `!=` or `Equals`, so make those work correctly, rather than requiring the user to do an unnatural thing. That is, you throw your users into "the pit of success" and they are automatically successful; they have to climb out of the pit to deliberately do it wrong.

Comment: Overloading == would mean both object are the same. But they differ in details. Object B is a modified view on object A (but they still share the same data base). I think it could be confusing if == returns true even some of the properties differ. I added some sample code to make my problem more clear.

Comment: You cannot change the design of the language. `==` between reference types _generally_ (in the absence of other overloads) means reference comparison. If you change your type (now known as `SomeData` in the new example code above) from a `class` into a `struct`, then `==` will be illegal (in the absence of a user-defined overload of `operator ==`). But of course you may not be interested in a value type in your case(?). Whoever wrote the buggy code did not understand what `==` means. The C# compiler could not guess this misunderstanding and warn about it.